# Can I hardlink my desktop folder to a different partition so I can put big files on it?

Tags: windows, file-management, symbolic-link, hardlink

Correct me if I'm wrong, but a hardlink is esentially like a shortcut that can trick applications to think it is a real folder. It allows you to specify an application to point to a shortcut to save its files and it will save that file in the actual location instead.

Does that mean I can delete my desktop folder and replace it with a hardlink pointing to an actual folder that is on a different partition? My SSD and C drive is currently quite full but I want to work with big files that I normally paste onto the desktop for easy access. I can create shortcuts for these files, but I deal with many files on the desktop that come and go and creating shortcuts every time would be a pain.

If I can use hardlinks this way, in what situations can't I use a hardlink for a similar purpose? I currently plan on hardlinking log folders of all my applications to my HDD so they don't write to the SSD (and so all the log files are in one place for easy viewing).

Answer (score 0):

To change your default desktop location and do the following:

Open the Registry editor (`regedit.exe`)
Browse to the location:
HKCU > Software > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > Explorer > User Shell Folders.
In the right window pane select the required value (i.e. Desktop).
Insert the new location for the folder to be stored.
Close the registry editor and log off.